# This code to filter data for javax swing table.After run it when I press OK, it show 0 data.but it starts work from 2nd press on OK button

Tags: java, swing

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import java.sql.Connection;

import java.sql.DriverManager;

import java.sql.ResultSet;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;



import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

import javax.swing.RowFilter;

import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;



import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;





public class My extends javax.swing.JFrame {

      DefaultTableModel model;
      Connection connect;
      Statement s;
      ResultSet rst;

      String expr;

      final TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> sorter;

    public My() {


        initComponents();
        model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
        sorter = new TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> (model);

    try {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        connect =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/SORTS","root",null);

        s = connect.createStatement();



        String sql = "SELECT * FROM  member";

        ResultSet rec = s.executeQuery(sql);

        int row = 0;

        while((rec!=null) && (rec.next()))

        {          

        model.addRow(new Object[0]);

        model.setValueAt(rec.getString("memberShipNo"), row, 0);

        model.setValueAt(rec.getString("name"), row, 1);

        model.setValueAt(rec.getString("workingStation"), row, 2);

        model.setValueAt(rec.getString("address"), row, 3);

        model.setValueAt(rec.getString("teleNo"), row, 4);

        model.setValueAt(rec.getString("email"), row, 5);


        row++;

        }

        rec.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {


            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        try {

            if(s != null) {

            s.close();

            connect.close();

        }

        }   catch (SQLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

        }

        jTable1.setRowSorter(sorter);        
       }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        System.out.println("3");
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        System.out.println("4");
        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {

            },
            new String [] {
                "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4", "Title 5", "Title 6"
            }
        ) {
            Class[] types = new Class [] {
                java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Object.class
            };

            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return types [columnIndex];
            }
        });
        System.out.println("5");

        System.out.println("2");
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);
        System.out.println("7");

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextField1.setText(" ");
        jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 375, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 25, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(47, 47, 47)
                        .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 125, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)))
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(111, 111, 111))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 143, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(60, 60, 60)
                        .addComponent(jButton1))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(51, 51, 51)
                        .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addGap(0, 11, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
       pack();
    }                         


    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
               if(evt.getSource()==jButton1){
               expr = jTextField1.getText();
               filter();

            sorter.setSortKeys(null);
            jTextField1.setText("");
         }
    }                                        

    private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

    }                                           

    protected void filter() {
        sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("^(?i)"+expr));

    }  


        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(My.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(My.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(My.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(My.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new My().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }


    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
  }
```

Comment: Please, please, please read the [help] section ***BEFORE*** asking your first question. It really will help you ask a better question and get better answers. It will tell you to put more effort into asking your question, to explain the details of your code, to make it easy for folks to be able to understand your problem and help you. Your question is vague, your amount of code dumped is huge, and **none** of it is explained. I'm voting to close this question until you improve it. A lot.

Answer (score 1):

So I tested it out with hard coded values (which you should *always* use with an MCVE that need database access), and the problem lies here

```
jTextField1.setText(" ");
```

When you first focus the text field, there is an extra space before the caret. It's hard to notice, but it's there. This causes the regex not the match, because `" Hello"` does not match `"Hello"`.

When you pressed the button, you explicitly set the text to `""` (no space), that's why it works. So you need to set the text of the text field initially to nothing (not even a space).

Comment: I got the idea.I changed the relavant code as          jTextField1.setText("");                                            as http://stackoverflow.com/users/2587435/peeskillet  mentioned.Now above whole code works properly.Thank you very much @peeskillet for your information and kind attention.